# How to configure Eslint to ignore particular errors in Vue Cli 3 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, snap.svg

I'm usig Snap.svg in Vue project, generated with Vue cli 3. 
Snap is added to vue.config.js as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule("i18n")
      .resourceQuery(/blockType=i18n/)
      .type("javascript/auto")
      .use("i18n")
      .loader("@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader")
      .end();

    config.module
      .rule("snapsvg")
      .test(require.resolve("snapsvg"))
      .use("imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0")
      .loader("imports-loader")
      .end();

  }
};
```

As well as to main.js

```
const snap = require(`imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0!snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js`);
```

I'm using snap in my components without local import.

```
var s = Snap(this.paper["svg-wrap"]);
```

The library works as excepted, svg is generated, however i keep getting Eslint errors.

```
error: 'Snap' is not defined (no-undef) at src\components\subpageBanner.vue:246:21:
```

I want to keep using Eslint in all components, but configure it to ingore this kind of errors.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a single file, then you can put the following line at the top of your file.

```js
/*eslint no-undef: "warning"*/
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what i need. I have to slightly modify it, according to eslint guides :  /*eslint no-undef: 1*/      (0=off,1=warn,2=error)